# openCV matchTemplate seems to not work when using PIL's ImageGrab

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv, computer-vision, python-3.7

Getting a screen shot.

```
    hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None,found)
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
    dimensions = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
    image = ImageGrab.grab(dimensions)
```

Converting it to a numpy array and to greyscale and unsigned 8bit/pixel:

```
    image=image.convert('RGB')
    image = numpy.array(image)
    cv_img = image.astype(np.uint8)
    cv_gray = cv2.cvtColor(cv_img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

However I keep getting this error: (-215) (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) && type == _templ.type() && _img.dims() <= 2 in function cv::matchTemplate - when I pass it to the matchTemplate function:

```
  result = cv2.matchTemplate(table_img,cv_img, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
```

Comment: You are passing `cv_img` to `matchTemplate`. What `data type` does `cv_img` has? What about `table_img`?

Comment: They are both np.ndarray

Comment: That's the type of the object, what's the type of the data? You must ensure that both the template and the target image have the same data type (8-bit or 32-bit floating-point).

Comment: cv_img = (image).astype(np.float32) and table_img = table_img.astype(np.float32))